weak functions behave differently on gcc/Linux and MinGW/Windows
I have set up a simple example to test for weak functions.
The example works as expected in Linux, but fails on Windows (compiled with MinGW):
FILE f.h:
#ifndef F_H
#define F_H 1

extern int func(void);

#endif

FILE f1.c:
#include "f.h"

int func(void) {
    return 17;
}

FILE f2.c:
#include "f.h"

__attribute__((weak)) int func(void) {
    return 3;
}

FILE main.c:
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

#include "f.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int x = func();

    printf("x is %d\n", x);

    return 0;
}

In f1.c I either name the function "func" or "qfunc".
If I use "func", then all compiles fine and func() is called from main().
If I use "qfunc" then:

On Linux it compiles and the output is 3.
On Windows I get an error:

c:/toolbase/mingw/comp_10.4.0_multilib_1f/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.4.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
main.o:main.c:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `func'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

In this case I analyze the object files:
C:\d\home\c\weak>nm f1.o
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
0000000000000000 T qfunc

C:\d\home\c\weak>nm f2.o
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 T .weak.func.
0000000000000000 r .xdata
                 w func

C:\d\home\c\weak>nm main.o
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
                 U __imp___acrt_iob_func
                 U __main
                 U __mingw_vfprintf
                 U func
0000000000000051 T main
0000000000000000 t printf

To my understanding the linker should use "func" that is marked "w" in f2.c.
The coommands I use to compile (exactly the same on both platforms):
gcc -c f1.c -o f1.o
gcc -c f2.c -o f2.o
gcc -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -o asd f1.o f2.o main.o

Does anybody have a hint what I need to do to make it work on Windows?
Thanks for any hints,
Torsten

How do you invoke your build command? Have you cleaned the object files it after renaming?

It works with MinGW64 with clang.

Try with the most recent MinGW-w64/GCC, like the one from https://winlibs.com/ or the one that can be installed via MSYS2's package manager pacman.

The build commands are shown above, I check the success manually with the gcc output.  Regarding the clang comment, do you have an example?

This seems to be a very old bug in MinGW: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9687
Hence, I think the only option for MinGW is some workaround not involving the weak definition feature.
